# Excel Formula to Select only items from a list which are within a limit based on selected criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

We are working with a table of hundreds of projects, with a total value well above our budget.  In order to prioritise the projects, we have decided to select the oldest projects first, selecting all up until our budget limit is met.

As an example, the below table shows the project (Column A), start date (Column B) and amount (Column C).  The budget amount is set at $3,500 but can be changed, but the total value of the projects are $5,000, so not all can be taken.  I would like to a formula for Column D (filled in here for illustration) which can select the projects up to $3,500 in order of the Start Date.

[image]

I've played around with this using the Small formula or other lengthy SUMIF calculations, but I can't seem to capture the Budget amount, which can be varied at any time, and building the relationship between the start date and the budget.

A side note is that the actual table is 100s of rows long with a budget over $10mil - in the example below the list excludes project 4 as adding it in would bring us over the budget, but in practice a formula which excludes most but includes project 4 because of the rounding issue would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
D4=IF($C$1>=SUMIFS($C$4:$C$9,$B$4:$B$9,"<=" & B4),C4,"-")
```

**PS.**

> using the Small formula or other lengthy SUMIF calculations

I'd recommend use SUMIFS() only. It can be easily extended with additional conditions whereas extending SUMIF() to SUMIFS() needs to re-order the function parameters.

Comment: This is exactly the formula I was looking for! Thanks for the quick help Akina - saved me many unproductive hours!

Comment: This won't work if you have a large value that cumulatively exceeds the limit at an early date.  For example, if the oldest date exceeds $3500, it should skip it and start with the next date (this formula selects no projects in that case).  Or, in the OP's data, substitute $2500 for the $350 for project 5.  This formula will stop with whatever the prior values total.  According to the question, it should skip the large value and continue selecting qualified projects from later dates.

Comment: @fixer1234 This exactly corresponds to the task. It is *select the oldest projects first, selecting all up until our budget limit is met* whereas you are offering to ignore "oldest projects first" condition and eject the most oldest project.

Comment: The problem is that it stops at the previous value as soon as any value puts it over budget.  The OP's example just happened not to include that situation.  I illustrated the problem in my answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's a result of author's "we have decided" - of course he must take this opportunity into account. But if he do it the task will alter.

Comment: @fixer1234 As I have said *use SUMIFS() only. It can be easily extended with additional conditions*. Taking into account your comment we can, for example, add one more filtering condition to SUMIFS(): `D4=IF($C$1>=SUMIFS($C$4:$C$9,$B$4:$B$9,"<=" & B4, $C$4:$C$9,"<" & $C$1),C4,"-")`. It skips all Amount values that exceeds Budget value.

Comment: I tried the formula above with my test data sorted back to project sequence (Amounts: 500, 1600, 1500, 400, 2500, 1250 in the question's order).  The result only included project 3.  I tried to come up with a formula similar to yours or Rajesh's to do this, but I didn't have enough coffee so that it didn't make my brain hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Akina and Rajesh H provided elegant solutions that work for the example in the question.  However, this approach has a shortcoming in that they stop too soon.  If you have a large project that **exceeds** the budget, either by itself or with the cumulative total, it stops with the previous project rather than skipping the non-qualifying project and continuing to look for other qualifying projects.  For example:

[image]

In the top case, I substituted a large project for the second one chronologically.  That would have pushed the cumulative over the budget, so it stopped with a single project instead of adding the later ones that would have been within budget.

In the second case, I made the earliest project larger than the budget.  Instead of skipping it and looking for later ones that qualified, it stops and returns nothing.

My assumption is that the objective is to fill the budget, giving priority to oldest projects first.  If an old project doesn't fit within the budget, I assume we shouldn't stop looking at that point.

Here's a straightforward solution that doesn't have that problem.

[image]

I've made several large value substitutions just to illustrate how the formula works.

As the first step, I sorted the data chronologically.  The first formula (in D4):

```
=IF(C4>$C$1,"",C4)
```

If the first value chronologically is under the budget amount it uses it, otherwise it leaves a null.  The rest of the formulas are copied from the second value (in D5):

```
=IF(SUM($D4:D$4)+C5>$C$1,"",C5)
```

This sums whatever previous qualifying values are above it and adds the value for that project.  If the project will put the total over budget, it posts a null, otherwise it adds the value for the project.  It does this for every subsequent project, so you always get all qualifying projects.

Note that you could improve on your strategy.  For example, your rules stop at $2400 for the values in my example.  You could get closer to the budget by adding other priorities that would allow selecting larger later projects over small early ones.  If your project list is as long as you describe, there will likely be many combinations close in time that could fill the budget.  By easing up on the oldest first constraint, you could get closer to budget.  You could also combine age with other objectives like project size; for example, complete a few big projects vs. many small ones.

Comment: It's better one and meets every point of concern you have shown through comments ,,, perfect 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

**This problem can be solved by use of the following formula also:**

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($C$4:$C$9)*($B$4:$B$9<=B4))<=$C$1,C4,"-")
```

Comment: This won't work if you have a large value that cumulatively exceeds the limit at an early date.  For example, if the oldest date exceeds $3500, it should skip it and start with the next date (this formula selects no projects in that case).  Or, in the OP's data, substitute $2500 for the $350 for project 5.  This formula will stop with whatever the prior values total.  According to the question, it should skip the large value and continue selecting qualified projects from later dates.

Comment: Thank @fixer1234 for valuable suggestion let  me go through once again,,,as you told, any correction/hints you would like  to pass , then plz just write."If 350 replaced by 2500 then it  selects Project 3 only. If 350 is 500 then it  selects Pr1, 2, 3, 5" !☺